# Prevent abbrev-mode from expanding on underscore

Tags: abbrev

Abbrev-mode seems to think an underscore signals a new word, which is not the case in many programming languages. I want it to expand after spaces, newlines, and tabs; not after underscores. Is there a way to tell abbrev-mode not to expand when I type an underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abbrev expansion behavior is built into the C code that implements `self-insert-command`. It looks up the syntactic class of the current and previous character in the buffer's [syntax table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html#Syntax-Tables) to decide whether to expand abbreviations.

In a programming mode for a language where the underscore is an identifier constituent, you may want to **change `_` to have word syntax**. This is a blunt instrument: every part of the system will then treat `_` as a word constituent, including motion commands. You may or may not like this. You can use [Subword mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Subword-Movement.html) to make the basic motion commands treat underscore as a word separator regardless of its declared syntax.

Incidentally, font locking has special support to use a different syntax table for highlighting. Many programming language modes use this to treat `_` as a word constituent for syntax highlighting.

```
(defun make-underscore-word-constituent (syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" syntax-table))
(eval-after-load "cc-mode" '(make-underscore-word-constituent c-mode-syntax-table))
```

If you don't like the secondary effects, you can make `_` a key that inserts `_` in any way other than self-insert, e.g. [by temporarily setting `abbrev-mode` to nil](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/651) or like this:

```
(defun self-insert-no-abbrev (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*p")
  (insert-char last-command-char arg))
(define-key c-mode-base-map "_" 'self-insert-no-abbrev)
```

This has a few side effects of its own, because `_` won't be self-inserting any more. For example, `_` will remain an undo barrier, it won't delete the selection under `delete-selection-mode`, etc. Some of these side effects may disappear if you add `(setq this-command 'self-insert-command)` to `self-insert-no-abbrev`, but not the ones I mentioned (I don't think there's a generic solution that will apply to `delete-selection`mode` since it runs before the command).

Comment: That is disappointing but also incredibly informative. This text box says I'm not supposed to say thanks here, but... Thanks :-)

Comment: Regarding changing the syntax table... This wouldn't affect subword-mode, would it? I'm thinking treating underscores as word constituents and also enabling subword-mode might be ideal.

Comment: @Avdi Subword mode won't be affected. That's a great idea to cancel the most obvious effect.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: The accepted answer on this question is not the optimal solution!*

Changing the syntax table is not neccesary to alter the behaviour of what is expanded and what not.

By default emacs uses indeed word syntax, i.e. non-word characters like `_` and `/` etc. can not occur in an abbrev.

However, this behaviour can be customized per abrrev-table.

See [Sect. 35.7 *Abbrev Table Properties*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Table-Properties.html) of the emacs manual.

With

```
(abbrev-table-put table :regexp val)
```

you can add an regular expression `val` instead of word-syntax to the abbrev-table `table`.

As I'm not so familiar with emacs regular expressions, I cannot give you the answer of what exactly you would need to put there in your case.

However, have a look at this answer on stackoverflow, you can start experimenting from the solution presented there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232384/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-non-backslashed-string-in-emacs-abbrev-mode

Answer (score 2):

This should be take care of it. It disables abbrev mode for any key you want. It's similar to the other answer, but you don't need to define a new function for each key.

```
(defun self-insert-no-abbrev ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((abbrev-mode nil))
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))

(global-set-key "_" #'self-insert-no-abbrev)
(global-set-key "." #'self-insert-no-abbrev)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993866/prevent-abbrev-expansion-after-certain-symbols-in-emacs) on SO: define some function to protect some key. Not sure if the best solution.