# How to prevent <RET> from triggering abbrev expansion?

Tags: abbrev

I am trying to stop emacs from expanding abbrevs after I press the `return` key. If I press `return`, I simply want to create a new line without expanding any abbrev at point.

I am relatively new at elisp. I’m assuming the answer involves `pre-abbrev-expand-hook`, but I haven’t found an answer in my research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent abbrev-mode from expanding on underscore](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/630/prevent-abbrev-mode-from-expanding-on-underscore)

Comment: @Tyler yes, I linked to that thread in the marked Answer below. Let me know if I should clarify further.

Comment: That's fine, no need to do anything further @Faulkner77. This question will probably end up getting closed, since it already has an answer in the linked post. That doesn't mean there's anything wrong here, just that we want to keep the site streamlined, with a single question/answer post for each issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this has been addressed after all in similar [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/651/33354) here that I found after the fact. The solution I settled on was as follows:

```
(defun my-self-insert-no-abbrev-RET ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((abbrev-mode nil))
    (newline nil t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "RET") #'my-self-insert-no-abbrev-RET)
```